# Should I use an async task on DB Upgrade? - No enclosing instance of type DBAdapter is accessible

Tags: android

I have a database, and I am upgrading the version now. The problem scenario is such that on the DB upgrade I have to read from a file and insert records into a primary database table. Before inserting a record I have to check if this record might already exist and based upon this make a decision of inserting or not inserting. There are tens of thousands of records, which I have to check and insert.

My question here is that would it be right to use a separate thread handler or an Async task on DB upgrade? Or does the system handle this?

Now I have created an AsyncTask

```
public class AsyncUpgrade extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,String>{




        @Override
        public void onPreExecute(){

            super.onPreExecute(); 
        }
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String result){
            //TODO


        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            System.out.println("UPGRADE 3");

            Cursor nameCur = readName();
            String name_friend = null; 
            if(nameCur != null && nameCur.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    name_friend = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("SelfName"));
                }while (nameCur.moveToNext());
            }


            assets = new AssetsDbHelper(con);
            Cursor mCur = assets.getMax_id();
            if(mCur != null && mCur.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    String name = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name"));
                    String DOB = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DOB"));
                    String imageData = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("imageUri"));
                    String type = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Type"));
                    String selection =  mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Radio"));

                    Cursor checkCur= checkIfRecordExists(name.trim(), DOB.trim()); 
                    if(checkCur != null && checkCur.moveToFirst()){

                    }else{
                        insertAdhoc(name, DOB,imageData, type, selection, name_friend);
                    }

                }while(mCur.moveToNext());




            }



            return "Success";
        }
    }
```

and I am calling the same from the upgrade method:

```
if(oldVersion <3){
                new AsyncUpgrade().execute();

            }
```

And now to my luck, I have an error popping up:

```
No enclosing instance of type DBAdapter is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type DBAdapter (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of DBAdapter).
```

Comment: use a separate thread handler or asynctask whatever is comfortable for you

Comment: WIll the thread outlive the lifecycle? I mean what about the normal program flow if the thread runs for long?

Answer (score 0):

Always use an asyctask.Whenever you are doing something which is not related to updating the UI thread.From [Android best practices for saving data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

> **Note**: Because they can be long-running, be sure that you call getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() in a background thread, such as with AsyncTask or IntentService.